# System Sounds in Java

Tags: java, system-sounds

I'm trying to code an error dialog, and I want it to call the proper system-specified sound. Is there any way to access system sounds from Java (i.e. Startup sound, default beep, asterisk, critical stop, etc.)?

**Note:** I know about `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();`

Comment: Are you meaning to play tunes with the PC Speaker? Or just cause a beep? I don't know how you play tunes but I sure would like to know.

Comment: I know how to play sound files, I want to know how to access an OS's default interface sounds

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here ya go (exclusively for windows:)

```
final Runnable runnable =
     (Runnable) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("win.sound.exclamation");
if (runnable != null) runnable.run();
```

More sounds for Windows (all pages contain the same content): [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html), [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html), [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html). (Good luck finding some for other OS!)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about windows system sounds?  My mac doesn't have a "critical stop" noise.  ;-)

You'll need to find the proper filesystem path to those sound files.  I assume they are wav files so something like this should work:

```
new JavaSoundAudioClip(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/go.wav"))).play();
```

The file may have a path such as:

```
C:\WINDOWS\MEDIA\Microsoft Office 2000\EXPLODE.WAV
```

NOTE: This will return immediately although the sound has been "queued" to the audio device.  You can call `stop()` if you need to stop it.

If you need to do something more special take a look at [this Java forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10764551#10764551).  Here's some documentation which breaks down how to use the [audio system more directly](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2173111/Java-Sound-Playing-Back-Audio-Files-using-Java.htm#Discussion%20and%20Sample%20Programs).

Comment: Oh, then find the sound files somewhere and include them in your jar/war.  Each operating systems has vastly different sounds (or none) and Java does not, as far as I know, provide a standard mechanism for triggering them.

Comment: @Supuhstar Me too, maybe I will supply my own sound effects.